# Ajax send and adds hidden characters

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, hidden-characters

I want to send something from one php site to another.
At the first site, everything seems fine.
The string seems like

> --show="author,book,text/n

but when i check the string after receiving it looks like

> --show="author,book,text/r/n

there is the problem, somehow it adds `/r` in the end.

First php:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#column_button").click(function(){
        var selected = [];
        $.each($("input[name='checkbox_columns']:checked"), function(){            
           selected.push($(this).val());
        });

        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("data", "--show=" + selected);
        //alert(JSON.stringify(selected));
        var ajax = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new activeXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        ajax.addEventListener("load", statusHandler2, false);
        ajax.open( 'post', 'showParameter.php', true );
        ajax.send(data);
        _("column_button").disabled=true;        
    });
});
```

Second php:

```
if(!empty($_POST['data'])){
    $data = $_POST['data'];}
```

So selected shows it right, but if i check the $data in the second php, it's wrong.

Comment: Your slashes are pointing the wrong way. It should be `\r` and `\n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be an issue where the servers are using different line ending types. Unix systems (Linux, BSD, etc) use `\n` (`LF`) by default, MacOS uses `\r` (`CR`)  where as Windows systems use `\r\n` (also known as `CRLF`). You may need to change your character encoding on one of the servers to the other.

`CR` = carriage return
`LF` = line feed

You could use code that will substitute the CRLF or CR with just an LF. [This page](https://www.darklaunch.com/2009/05/06/php-normalize-newlines-line-endings-crlf-cr-lf-unix-windows-mac) shows how you can achieve this simply.

Comment: The problem is, i am reading in csv files, so some of them end with /r some with /n and some with r/n/ so i dont want ajax to just send /n or /r, i want ajax not to change what i am sending, so that it dont change the line feed at the of the post data

Comment: I actually can do it the ugly way: check which line end the string has before i send it, and then replace the new line end after receiving with the old one. But i would prefere a more beautiful solution?

Comment: I will change the uploaded file with sed, can someone tell me how to sed from unix to dos, and from unix to unix format? sed -i 's/$/\r\n/'